# Number of tiles in civilization

Tags: civilization-5

How many tiles are there in each different sized civ 5 map? Including all land and water tiles.

Answer (score 3):

In a [post on the wonderful Civ-Fanatics forum](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showpost.php?p=9744856&postcount=3), the map sizes are:

> Duel:      40 x 25  (2 players, 4 city-states, 2 natural wonders)
>
> Tiny:      56 x 36  (4 players, 8 city-states, 3 natural wonders)
>
> Small:     66 x 42  (6 players, 12 city-states, 3 natural wonders)
>
> Standard:  80 x 52  (8 players, 16 city-states, 4 natural wonders)
>
> Large:    104 x 64  (10 players, 20 city-states, 6 natural wonders)
>
> Huge:     128 x 80  (12 players, 24 city-states, 7 natural wonders)